# In Magento 2, How can i get current product id via custom module at admin panel

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.2.5, how can i get current product id at admin panel ?
Actually i have created a module at product edit page admin panel, There i wants to get current product id like frontend we use `$this->_registry->registry('current_product');`

Please suggest me correct script.

Answer (score -1):

You can basically do it the same way as you already do on frontend. In your Block Class, include registry and then use it in your method, like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\...;

class Dummy
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
       ...
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       ...     
    )
    {
       ...
       $this->_registry = $registry;
       ...
    } 

    public function dummyfunction()
    {
       $_product_id = $this->_registry->registry('product'))->getId();
    } 
}
```

Alternatively use object manager, like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$_product_id = $product->getId();
```

Comment: Hello Tobi, Thanks for reply.  I tried this but they show me this error(I attached screenshot) https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3762222/0073f7b1573e95ebb7e2f1d0eddafc95

Comment: Hey Vijay, do you get the same error for both ways?

Comment: Yes Tobi, I tried with both ways. But it didn't show me product id.